# Javascript: Regex for "DD/MM/YY HH:SS" not succeeding

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following datetime string: `09/07/2020 02:00`

I need to check the format of the string before apply `Date.parse()` to ensure that it's in the correct format. I've developed a regular expression for the string however it doesn't appear to work in Javascript. I've tested it and it works in regex tester but not in js. Example (regex101) [here](https://regex101.com/r/HYtfqz/1)

**REGEX**

***String***

```
09/07/2020 02:00
```

***Expression***

```regex
^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))(\/)([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])(\/)\d\d\d\d (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d$
```

```js
function clean_inputdatetime(datetime) {
  var cleaned_datetime = null
  var datetime_regex_cond = RegExp('/^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))(\/)([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])(\/)\d\d\d\d (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d$/', 'g')
  var regex_success = datetime_regex_cond.test(datetime)
  if (regex_success) {
    var cleaned_datetime = Date.parse(datetime)
  }
  return [regex_success, cleaned_datetime]
}
console.log(
 clean_inputdatetime("09/07/2020 02:00")
)
```

*Note `regex_success` returns **false*** for above.

Comment: Double escape the backslash in the RegExp constructor.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Nope: https://regex101.com/r/E2OTWg/1

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._ Just remove the wrapping slashes and double escape the backslashes or use `datetime_regex_cond = /^...$/;`

Comment: @mplungjan Yup, double escape the backslash using `RegExp('` or use the regex literal `RegExp(/` with the current pattern or just the regex literal `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `RegExp` you need to remove the enclosing slashes - otherwise they will be included in the regex itself. Also you need to correctly escape the string:

```
const datetime_regex_cond = new RegExp('^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))(\\/)([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])(\\/)\\d\\d\\d\\d (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\\d):[0-5]?\\d$','g')
```

Or simply do:

```
const datetime_regex_cond = /^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))(\/)([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])(\/)\d\d\d\d (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d$/g;
```

Comment: Typo type question  - could be voted to be closed

Comment: Yeah you're right - I'll vote for close as well but leave the answer just in case :)

Comment: That's done the trick, thankyou!